# Ubuntu first cold boot of each day freezes and i have to reboot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, 64-bit, amd-ryzen

I have ubuntu 20.04lts installed on one ssd, and windows 10 on another ssd. I have a ryzen 5 5600g processor on a b450 msi board. From the bios I have selected ubuntu (grub) as the main boot, and I have disabled windows. So far no problems.

The problem occurs when **I start the computer, and I do not press any keys.** What happens is that it loads the linux GRUB, and the countdown starts, and **ubuntu starts** by default (I have two kernels 5.13.0-39-generic and 5.13.0-40-generic) **but the desktop freezes, and ubuntu runs very, very slow.**

I have noticed, that this does not happen if I myself select from grub that I want to start ubuntu. This phenomenon only occurs when without pressing any key other than the power-on button, ubuntu starts by itself.

I have done several tests, I have tried with packages, dependencies, etc. But I think the problem is not there, because **how can it be that by pressing a single key on the keyboard the system works correctly?**

I repeat, this only happens the first time of each day, when I turn on the computer for the first time and without touching any key other than the power button. Otherwise this doesn't happen. For example, if after that I restart the computer, and let the countdown run, it doesn't happen anymore. Or if I turn it off, and turn it on again, neither.

I've been thinking, what if it's a hardware issue? And if ubuntu does not recognize all the processor cores well, or it does not load the RAM memory well, or the graphics do not work well until I press a simple key, that draws a little more power to the system. It has to be something related to the cold, or to the current that reaches the system.

Regarding the configuration of the mother, I have not made any changes that have to do with overclocking. All settings are as default (except the bios version that I have updated) and the boot selection mentioned above.

I would like to know what could be the cause of this problem. And if possible from the software side how to fix it.

**UPDATE 5/5/2022**

I have noticed with the commands: lscpu, lsmod, htop , sudo dmidecode --type memory | less. If there was something out of place, and everything seems to be in order. Tomorrow I'm going to see if it's the graphics card, which for some reason doesn't take enough current or something on the first boot. I'm going to try connecting the hdmi to the integrated video and see if that works correctly.

**update 5/6/2022**

Apparently it's a graphics problem.  Today I did the test on the first boot, it froze as usual, but this time I changed the hdmi input of the graphics card (rx 550 2gb) to the integrated one of ryzen 5600g (without turning off).  And the result was that it worked correctly.  Then I tried to connect to the graphic again without turning off and it stayed black screen.  One piece of information (perhaps irrelevant) when it was changed to integrated, it was changed to 1920x1080, I always use 1366x768.

Now it is clear to me that it is a graphics problem (I have installed the privative amd drivers that Ubuntu itself offers) But....  that still does not respond **why restarting solves the problem? why if I press any key on first boot no problem either?**

Comment: Is your keyboard wireless? Can you test with a wired keyboard. I'm thinking perhaps the keyboard is making errors (eg related to low power mode) -- if it's USB then they should appear in dmesg/syslog. Does it run properly from live USB drive?

Comment: my keyboard is wired,but with rgb lights .  My cabinet also has rgb. Could it be a low power problem related to the graphics or the rgb lights? (which turn on without problem) Should I look in syslog/dmesg?